# Store and label image in a 2D-Array for Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-recognition, labeling

I want do a image recognition with Tensorflow for three different image classes. My problem now is to label the images for my training set and store it in a 2D-Array for using it in the recognition. I already used a methode to store 2 classes (in the code example is it **X** and **Y**), but now i wanna do it also for a third class (In the code named with **Z**.

```
import cv2                 # working with, mainly resizing, images
import numpy as np         # dealing with arrays
import os                  # dealing with directories
from random import shuffle # mixing up current data
from tqdm import tqdm      # percentage bar for tasks
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression


TRAIN_DIR = 'MYPATH'
TEST_DIR = 'MYPATH'
IMG_SIZE = 80 
# learning rate
LR = 1e-5

MODEL_NAME = 'name-{}-{}.model'.format(LR, '2conv-basic')

# convert image and label information to array information
def label_img(img):
    #split images
    word_label = img.split('.')[-3]
    if word_label == 'X': return [1,0] 
    elif word_label == 'Y': return [0,1]
    elif word_label == 'Z' : return [???]

# create training data array
def create_train_data():
    training_data = []
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):
        label = label_img(img)
        path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR,img)
        img = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
        training_data.append([np.array(img),np.array(label)])
    shuffle(training_data)
    np.save('train_data.npy', training_data)
    return training_data

def process_test_data():
    testing_data = []
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TEST_DIR)):
        path = os.path.join(TEST_DIR,img)
        img_num = img.split('.')[1]
        img = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
        testing_data.append([np.array(img), img_num])

    shuffle(testing_data)
    np.save('test_data.npy', testing_data)
    return testing_data

train_data = create_train_data()
# if you already have train data:
#train_data = np.load('train_data.npy')

import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()

convnet = input_data(shape=[None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1], name='input')

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 2, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 2)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 2, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 2)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 2, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 2)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 2, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 2)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 2, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 2)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 2, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 2)

convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 1024, activation='relu')
convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8)

convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 2, activation='softmax')
convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR, loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')

model = tflearn.DNN(convnet, tensorboard_dir='log')

if os.path.exists('{}.meta'.format(MODEL_NAME)):
    model.load(MODEL_NAME)
    print('model loaded!')

train = train_data[:-500]
test = train_data[-500:]

X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
Y = [i[1] for i in train]

test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
test_y = [i[1] for i in test]

model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=15, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}), 
    snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)

model.save(MODEL_NAME)

# if you need to create the data:
test_data = process_test_data()
# if you already have some saved:
#test_data = np.load('test_data.npy')

fig=plt.figure()

for num,data in enumerate(test_data[:12]):

    img_num = data[1]
    img_data = data[0]

    y = fig.add_subplot(3,4,num+1)
    orig = img_data
    data = img_data.reshape(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
    #model_out = model.predict([data])[0]
    model_out = model.predict([data])[0]

    if np.argmax(model_out) == 1: str_label='X'
    else: str_label='Y'

    y.imshow(orig,cmap='gray')
    plt.title(str_label)
    y.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    y.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a class, just expand the dimension of your image label arrays:

```
# convert image and label information to array information
def label_img(img):
    #split images
    word_label = img.split('.')[-3]
    if word_label == 'X': return [1,0,0] 
    elif word_label == 'Y': return [0,1,0]
    elif word_label == 'Z' : return [0,0,1]
```

You will also need to update the softmax classifier to handle 3 classes:

```
convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 3, activation='softmax')
```

You will also need to disable the loading of the old model.  The old model is only valid for the old graph, but since it is being changed we have to start from scratch.

```
###
if os.path.exists('{}.meta'.format(MODEL_NAME)):
    model.load(MODEL_NAME)
    print('model loaded!')
###
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but when i do it so i get this error: 

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 3) for Tensor 'targets/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 2)'